# Knight's destination using recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, backtracking, chess

I've been working on a project which needs the knight(we have it's coordinates at the start) travel to destination(also known coordinates).
I tried to write using recursion but my code doesn't seem to be doing anything and I can't find the problem. Here's my code:

```
static bool Kelias(int dabX, int dabY, string[] Lenta, int dX, int dY, int indeksas)
{
    if (dabX == dX && dabY == dY)
        return true;
    if (!Lenta[dabY][dabX].Equals('0'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (indeksas > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder naujas = new StringBuilder(Lenta[dabY]);

        naujas[dabX] = (char)indeksas;

        Lenta[dabY] = naujas.ToString();
    }

    // aukstyn desinen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX + 2, dabY + 1)
            && Kelias(dabX + 2, dabY + 1, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    // aukstyn desinen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX + 1, dabY + 2)
            && Kelias(dabX + 1, dabY + 2, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    // aukstyn kairen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX - 1, dabY + 2)
            && Kelias(dabX - 1, dabY + 2, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }
    // aukstyn kairen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX - 2, dabY + 1)
            && Kelias(dabX - 2, dabY + 1, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // zemyn kairen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX - 2, dabY - 1)
            && Kelias(dabX - 2, dabY - 1, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // zemyn kairen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX - 1, dabY - 2)
            && Kelias(dabX - 1, dabY - 2, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // zemyn desinen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX + 1, dabY - 2)
            && Kelias(dabX + 1, dabY - 2, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // zemyn desinen
    if (GaliJudeti(dabX + 2, dabY - 1)
            && Kelias(dabX + 2, dabY - 1, Lenta, dX, dY, indeksas + 1))
    {
        return true;
    }

    indeksas--;
    return false;
}

static bool GaliJudeti(int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < 8 && y < 8)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A little explanation about the variables and what I'm trying to do:

dabX, dabY - are the current coordinates of the Knight

Lenta - is my board(it's a string cause I'm reading the starting data from a txt file).

dX, dY - is the target destination

indeksas - is a tracker of how many moves it takes to reach the destination

Now the first if checks if we reached the destination. Second one checks if the coordinates to which we're traveling too are not obstructed(Since my board is made out of zeroes cause it's in a string we check if the symbol is equal to it cause if it's not means path is obstructed). Then we move onto the knights possible movements which is the main part of the method.

Also there's another function called GaliJudeti which checks if we're in bounds of the board(8x8).

Comment: If you have the option to pick your game to implement, consider doing something simpler like TicTacToe instead. Doing a Chess Game is pretty advanced and not something I would choose to do if I had the option. If you need to check if it works at all, that is what Breakpoints are there for(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints) Once you do have one, you can inspect the value of variables and follow the exact logic.

Comment: It's not a game it's just an exercise on recursion..

Comment: The variable names are in my native language(it makes sense if you know it) so I'm sorry I could not explain it better.

Comment: Don't know if your "obstructed" part means this, but generally you would have to keep track of where you are coming from so you don't just move back and forth between two positions (or go round in circles).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like it must work. I just used your algorithm, modified it a bit and everything works fine. I used classes to make it look more generally, but in fact it's all the same.

```
static bool MoveFirstSolution(Knight knight, Board board, Point destination, int counter, Trace trace)
{
    board.Set(knight.X, knight.Y, counter);
    if (knight.IsInPoint(destination))
    {       
        //trace is an object to store found path         
        trace.Counter = counter;
        trace.Board = board;                   
        return true;
    }
    counter++;
    Point[] moves = knight.AllPossibleMoves();
    foreach (Point point in moves)
    {
        if (board.Contains(point) && board.IsFree(point))
        {
            knight.MoveTo(point);
            if (MoveFirstSolution(knight, board.GetCopy(), destination, counter, trace))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However, this function will find first solution and stop. If you want best solution, you need to continue the search even when the answer is found. Here is a function to perform it:

```
static void Move(Knight knight, Board board, Point destination, int counter, Trace trace)
{
    board.Set(knight.X, knight.Y, counter);
    if (knight.IsInPoint(destination))
    {
        if (!trace.IsShorterThen(counter))
        {
            trace.Counter = counter;
            trace.Board = board;
            Console.WriteLine("Better trace");
            Console.WriteLine("Counter: " + trace.Counter);
            Console.WriteLine(trace.Board);
        }
        return;
    }
    counter++;
    Point[] moves = knight.AllPossibleMoves();
    foreach(Point point in moves)
    {
        if (board.Contains(point) && board.IsFree(point))
        {
            knight.MoveTo(point);
            Move(knight, board.GetCopy(), destination, counter, trace);
        }
    }
}
```

The trace is overwritten each time when better one is found. But for 8 * 8 board it takes really long time to execute.

For your code I can advise to try `Console.WriteLine()` to be sure, that everything works. Maybe, you `Lenta` is not overwritten, as you expected and this causes infinite recursion. Try tracking each action of your function, to find the source of problem.

Here are my main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Knight knight = new Knight(0, 0);
    Board board = new Board(8, 8);
    Point destination = new Point(0, 4);
    Trace bestTrace = new Trace();
    MoveFirstSolution(knight, board, destination, 1, bestTrace);

    Console.WriteLine("Best trace: " + bestTrace.Counter);
    Console.WriteLine(bestTrace.Board);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and the rest of required classes, so you can try it as working example.

```
class Trace
{
    public Trace()
    {
        this.Board = null;
        this.Counter = -1;
    }
    public Trace(Board board, int counter)
    {
        this.Board = board;
        this.Counter = counter;
    }
    public bool IsShorterThen(int counter)
    {
        return this.Counter > 0 && this.Counter <= counter;
    }
    public Board Board { get; set; }
    public int Counter { get; set; }
}
class Board
{
    private int[][] _board;
    public Board(int N, int M)
    {
        this._board = new int[N][];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            this._board[i] = new int[M];
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                this._board[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    public int N
    {
        get
        {
            return this._board.Length;
        }
    }
    public int M
    {
        get
        {
            return this._board.Length > 0 ? this._board[0].Length : 0;
        }
    }
    public Board GetEmptyCopy()
    {
        return new Board(this.N, this.M);
    }
    public Board GetCopy()
    {
        Board b = new Board(this.N, this.M);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            {
                b.Set(i, j, this.Get(i, j));
            }
        }
        return b;
    }
    public bool Contains(int i, int j)
    {
        return (i >= 0) && (i < this.N) && (j >= 0) && (j < this.M);
    }
    public bool Contains(Point point)
    {
        return this.Contains(point.X, point.Y);
    }
    public bool IsFree(int i, int j)
    {
        return this._board[i][j] == 0;
    }
    public bool IsFree(Point point)
    {
        return this.IsFree(point.X, point.Y);
    }
    public void Set(int i, int j, int val)
    {
        this._board[i][j] = val;
    }
    public int Get(int i, int j)
    {
        return this._board[i][j];
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string str = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < this.N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.M; j++)
            {
                str += String.Format("{0, 3}", this._board[i][j]);
            }
            str += "\r\n";
        }
        return str;
    }
}
class Knight
{        
    public Knight(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
    public Point[] AllPossibleMoves()
    {
        Point[] moves = new Point[8];
        moves[0] = new Point(this.X + 1, this.Y + 2);
        moves[1] = new Point(this.X + 1, this.Y - 2);
        moves[2] = new Point(this.X + 2, this.Y + 1);
        moves[3] = new Point(this.X + 2, this.Y - 1);
        moves[4] = new Point(this.X - 1, this.Y + 2);
        moves[5] = new Point(this.X - 1, this.Y - 2);
        moves[6] = new Point(this.X - 2, this.Y + 1);
        moves[7] = new Point(this.X - 2, this.Y - 1);
        return moves;
    }
    public bool IsInPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        return this.X == x && this.Y == y;
    }
    public bool IsInPoint(Point point)
    {
        return this.IsInPoint(point.X, point.Y);
    }
    public void MoveTo(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    public void MoveTo(Point point)
    {
        this.MoveTo(point.X, point.Y);
    }
}
class Point
{
    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
    }
    public int X { get; private set; }
    public int Y { get; private set; }
}
```